# Retrying Kafka errors using @RetryableTopic

Tags: spring-kafka

Is there a way to specify the dlt used when retrying with spring-kafka [@RetryableTopic](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#using-the-retryabletopic-annotation).

I use a listener with the following configuration :

```
    @RetryableTopic(
  attempts = "4",
  backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000),
  autoCreateTopics = "false",
  topicSuffixingStrategy = TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_DELAY_VALUE,
  fixedDelayTopicStrategy = FixedDelayStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC)
  @KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.template.default-topic}")
```

This retries using a single topic but uses my main topic +"_dlt" for exhausted retries even though I have a dead letter topic with a different name configured at :

```
spring:
kafka:
 consumer:
 template:
  dead-letter-topic: its_dead_jim
```

I've used a DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer in the past and have implemented the dlt resolver function but I don't see a way to override the default behavior in the documentation for RetryableTopic. I've looked at [RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/retrytopic/RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder.html) and [RetryTopicConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/retrytopic/RetryTopicConfigurer.html)

but nothing seem applicable to change the DLT name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you think there is such a property on the `template`.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-naming-strategies).

Extend `RetryTopicConfigurationSupport` in a `@Configuration` class and...

> **Custom naming strategies**

> More complex naming strategies can be accomplished by registering a bean that implements RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory. The default implementation is SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory and a different implementation can be registered in the following way:

```java
@Override
protected RetryTopicComponentFactory createComponentFactory() {
    return new RetryTopicComponentFactory() {
        @Override
        public RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory retryTopicNamesProviderFactory() {
            return new CustomRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory();
        }
    };
}
```

As an example the following implementation, in addition to the standard suffix, adds a prefix to retry/dl topics names:

```java
public class CustomRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory implements RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory {

    @Override
    public RetryTopicNamesProvider createRetryTopicNamesProvider(
                DestinationTopic.Properties properties) {

        if(properties.isMainEndpoint()) {
            return new SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProvider(properties);
        }
        else {
            return new SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProvider(properties) {

                @Override
                public String getTopicName(String topic) {
                    return "my-prefix-" + super.getTopicName(topic);
                }

            };
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are correct sir! Thanks for pointing out that documentation.