# Spring kafka Consumer with @RetryableTopic is not working as expected

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Spring kafka Consumer is creating a Topic when autoCreateTopic is set to false and is there a way to specify our own topic .here's my code

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class RetryConsumer {

    @RetryableTopic(
            attempts = "4",
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000),
            autoCreateTopics="false",
            kafkaTemplate="consumerKafkaTemplate",
             include = RuntimeException.class)
    @KafkaListener(topicPartitions = {@TopicPartition(topic = "bookStore")
            
    public void listen(Message message, Acknowledgement ack) {

        log.info("Message Recieved from Topic ::"+message.getHeaders().get("topic"));
    }

    //for Testing Purpose
     public void consumeException(String message){
     throw new RuntimeException("Exception for Message "+message);
}

in kafka Template im setting a DefaultTopic
```

I have tried overriding RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory(Used similar on in this question : [Retrying Kafka errors using @RetryableTopic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75063953/retrying-kafka-errors-using-retryabletopic) ) and tried returning the topic name which i want it to use but im getting an exception saying : ERROR while Fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : topic=UNKOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION

Answer (score 0):

With `autoCreateTopics="false"`, the topics must exist already (or you need to add `NewTopic` beans for each one so that the framework will create them - but that makes no sense - `autoCreateTopics="true", the default - does exactly that).

Comment: if we set autoCreateTopics to false and how do we pass the existing topics to it.Thank you

Comment: You have to provide a custom naming strategy - see the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-naming-strategies